# Session message not being displayed

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a php file named settings_email.php that has the form for a user to change his/her email and when the user press submit it goes to the second php file named includes/changeemail.php to Update the table then send him/her back to the same page with a message that it was successful while carrying the users id because the initial page uses it. Yet no message is displayed and the email update is successful. Have I misused anything? Do I need to include anything else? Is there a better way to do it?

settings_email.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['flash'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['flash'];
    unset($_SESSION['flash']);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
....
</head>
<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

includes/changeemail.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbh.inc.php';
if (isset($_POST['changeemail'])) {
    //Error Handlers
    if(){
        ....
    }else{
        $_SESSION['flash'] = 'Success';
        header("Location: ../settings_email.php?settingsemail=".$id );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to to echo within the body tag not outside the html tags

Comment: yeah you are right  thank you so much and sorry for wasting your time I am new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this : echo inside the body tag and don't forget to over php "?>".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
....
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['flash'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['flash'];
    unset($_SESSION['flash']);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `session_start();` should infact be the first line within a document..Or you will get headers already send error.

Comment: yeah it was pointed out to me by @RaymondNijland that it has to be echoed from within the html tags. Nonetheless, thank you for helping